# Construct a polyline from AABBTree

Tags: c++, 3d, polyline, aabb

I need to find an intersection polyline of 2 meshes. I have an implementation of AABBTree which find segments and triangles of intersection, Now I need to construct a polyline from them  which defines the boundary of the intersection.I  prefer not to use CGAL or any other library
I looking for some kind of algorithm of code implementation